# Don't display html if custom field is empty

Tags: custom-field, tabs

I'm using the plugin [WP UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ui/) on my custom post type to display the content in tabs. I'm doing this in the template for the custom post type not using the shortcode provided by the plugin. I'm also using Advanced Custom Fields for the fields on the custom post type.

However sometimes there won't be any content for the custom fields. The page will then display the tab but it will be empty.

In my template i have divs that are used to display the content in tabs. So in my template i have the div for the tab and then the custom field.

```
                <!-- Videos Tab -->

  <h3 class="wp-tab-title">Videos</h3>

  <div class="wp-tab-content">

        <?php the_field('videos'); ?>

   </div><!-- Close Videos -->
```

Is it possible to hide the tab if there is no content in the custom field? i.e. not output the div so therefore it won't display the tab.

Thanks

So there's no confusion, the_field is a function used by advanced custom fields to display the contents of the custom field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with WP UI, but the following code might do the trick:

```
            <!-- Videos Tab -->

<h3 class="wp-tab-title">Videos</h3>

<?php if (get_field('videos') && get_field('videos') != "") { ?>

    <div class="wp-tab-content">

        <?php the_field('videos'); ?>

    </div><!-- Close Videos --> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it will work. the_field() do an echo()

Comment: I tried this but this just hides the tabs even if there is something in them. Also i've updated the question regarding the_field()

Comment: i changed my code - replaced the_field by get_field - i think this should work since get_field just returns the value instead of echoing...