# Don't display html if function returns nothing

Tags: functions

This question is very similar to the one below however it requires a different solution.

[Don't display html if custom field is empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35037/dont-display-html-if-custom-field-is-empty)

I'm using the plugin Related Posts Thumbnails but i'm using the template tag in my template file to display related products.

```
<?php get_related_posts_thumbnails(); ?>
```

[Plugin Source](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/related-posts-thumbnails/trunk/related-posts-thumbnails.php)

I've got this contained inside of a div with a title so the output looks a bit better. However if there isn't any related products i need it to hide the div otherwise it just displays an empty area.

This is the code i'm using.

```
<div id="relatedproducts">
    <h1>Related Products</h1>
    <?php get_related_posts_thumbnails(); ?></div>
```

Is it possible to not show this div if the function returns no related products?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
global $related_posts_thumbnails;
if ($related_posts_thumbnails->get_html()) { ?>

    <div id="relatedproducts">
        <h1>Related Products</h1>
        <?php get_related_posts_thumbnails() ?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

A quick look at the `get_related_posts_thumbnails()` shows that it is simply echoing the HTML returned from the `get_html()` method of the `$related_posts_thumbnails` object. By checking the returned HTML first, you can make sure it is not an empty string (or any falsy value).

Note for the plugin author: picking the name `get_related_posts_thumbnails()` and making it *echo* the output is quite unintuitive. Other WordPress functions use the `get_` prefix for functions that return data, and leave it out to echo it. For example: `get_bloginfo('url')` vs `bloginfo('url')`.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin's function echos the output and does not return it. But the plugin has a **shortcode**, which you can use to get what you want.

```
<?php
$thumbs = do_shortcode('[related-posts-thumbnails]');
if(strlen($thumbs) > 0)
{?
    <div id="relatedproducts">
    <h1>Related Products</h1>
        <?php echo $thumbs; ?>
    </div>
<?php }
?>
```

Try this and let me know.